# 'Bool' is not convertible to 'Binding<Bool>' in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have a `SwiftUI` native Watch app I Am working on. I have a `Combine` based class that allows me to store `\userDefaults, one of which is a simple toggle.

```
import SwiftUI  
import Foundation  
import Combine  


class MeetingSetup: BindableObject {  

    let willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()  

    var twitterEnabled: Bool = false {  
        didSet {  
            willChange.send()  
        }  
    }  

    init() {  
        let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.appname")!  
        twitterEnabled = prefs.bool(forKey: "keyTwitterEnabledBool")  
    }  
}
```

In the `SwiftUI` I am getting the error messages that `Bool` is not convertible to `Binding<Bool>`

```
import SwiftUI  
import Combine  

struct SetupView : View {  

    @ObjectBinding var meetingSetup: MeetingSetup = delegate.meetingSetup  

    var body: some View {  

                HStack{  
                    Toggle(isOn: self.meetingSetup.twitterEnabled){  // <== 'Bool' in not convertible to 'Binding<Bool>'  
                        Text("Twitter")  
                    }  
    }  
}
```

I don't understand why this is getting the message since the code is `@ObjectBinding`, should it not be `Binding<Bool>` by definition?  If not how do I address this correctly??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the dollar sign:

```swift
Toggle(isOn: self.$meetingSetup.twitterEnabled) { ... }
```

I also noticed that you are using `didSet`in your `@BindableObject`, but you should really be using `willSet`.

And finally, maybe you pasted incompletely, but you are missing a closing bracket in your view.

***If you don't know what the dollar sign is for, check the WWDC2019 video Data Flow in SwiftUI.***

Comment: Thank you!  This helped.. the missing bracket was from paste issue. So didSet means that the change comes from the datastore, while willSet means it is coming from the screen?  or do I need to have both a didSet and a willSet setup?

Comment: So do I use willSet to show that the initial data comes from the screen verses the dataset?

Comment: When your bindable object changes a value, you need to make SwiftUI aware of it. You do so, by calling willChange.send(). Before beta 4, you would call it just **after** the change to the variable was made. So we used to call it inside a didSet. Since beta 4, Apple changed the BindableObject protocol, and the notification must be done just **before** it is made. So now, we only use willSet to call willChange.send(). As for the changes made by SwiftUI (i.e., when you flip the switch), you do not have to do anything. By using a binding, the framework takes care of that.

Comment: The fact that Apple made this change in beta 4, is the reason why you will see so many examples using didSet, they were written before last Monday when beta 4 was released.